# Crystal Reports Grouping sum by Date

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Hi I'm using Crystal Reports 2008. And I have an output of like this:

```
    Date (dd/mm/yyyy)     Weight
   -----------------------------------------
    01-01-2013            5000
    01-01-2013            1500
    02-01-2013            2000
    02-01-2013            4500
    03-01-2013            5700
    03-01-2013            5800
```

Now, my question how can I sum it and group by Date and the output should be:

```
    Date (dd/mm/yyyy)     Weight
   -----------------------------------------
    01-01-2013            6500
    02-01-2013            6500
    03-01-2013            11500
```

Thanks,

Captain16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select Weight field.
- Select Insert | Summary...

[image]

- Change 'Calculate this summary:' to Sum
- Click Insert Group... to create a group on the date field

[image]

- Select date field and set 'This section will be printed' to 'for each month'
- Click OK to close Insert Group dialog
- Select new group from the Summary location (if not already chosen), then OK

Comment: The 'This section will be printed' should be 'for each day'.  I would have edited the answer, but it is in one of the screenshots too.

Comment: Thank you.. It works perfectly!! Yes I used as "for each Day".

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a Group field for   Date (dd/mm/yyyy)
2. Then create a summary field, operates on the group you created. The summary field should ask for the sum of weight
3. Drag the group name and summary field to the group header.